# Create a python class with a uniqure feature

Tags: python, list, class

I have a bunch of interdependent variables that I want to save in a list of class elements. Now I want it to be sorted according to one of the class features. At the moment, what I am doing is this:

```
    class myclass(object):
      lst_of_A=[]
      def __init__(self, Attr_A, Attr_B, Attr_C):
        self.A=Attr_A
        self.B=[Attr_B]
        self.C=[Attr_C]
        self.lst_of_A.append(Attr_A)
      def append_to_existing_entry(self, Attr_B, Attr_C):
        self.B.append(Attr_B)
        self.C.append(Attr_C)
```

Now, I use try and except in a for loop to generate the list accordingly:

```
    my_lst_of_classes=[]
    for el in read_in_data:
      try:
        ind=my_lst_of_classes[0].lst_of_A.index(el[0])
        my_lst_of_classes[index].append_to_existing_entry(el[1],el[2])
      except:
        my_lst_of_classes.append(myclass(el[0],el[1],el[2]))
```

This works, but seems very clumsy. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: at least replace `except:` by `except ValueError:`

Comment: Here is my understanding of your problem: You have a list of tuples `(a, b, c)` in `read_in_data`. You want to *group* (and not *sort*) the `b` and `c` value of each `a` (with duplicates). Not clear if fact, even after running your code on some example. Can you explain?

Comment: Sry for not being clear enough. Your understanding is mostly correct, but the input is not necessarily a tuple, in my case it is a list of lists. For my data they would be, e.g., read_in_data[0][0] = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0], read_in_data[0][1]=[0, 2, 4] and read_in_data[0][2]=[1,1,-1,1]. Then follows read_in_data[1][0]=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0], read_in_data[1][1]=[0,2,6] and read_in_data[1][2]=[1,1,-1,1]. (So, read_in_data[0][0]=read_data[1][0] and read_in_data[0][2]=read_in_data[1][2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, you want to use a `dict` (or `OrderedDict` if insertion order matters) instead of a `list` - this makes for more readable and much faster code.

Second point, you want to encapsulate all the handling of this collection (specially the "create or extend" part) so the client code doesn't have to care about it.  `classmethod`s (methods that take the class - not the instance - as first argument) are your friend here.

Here's a simple example that should get you started:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyObj(object):
    _index = OrderedDict()

    @classmethod
    def insert(cls, a, b, c):
        if a in cls._index:
            cls._index[a].extend(b, c)
        else:
            cls._index[a] = cls(a, b, c)

    @classmethod
    def list_instances(cls):
        return cls._index.values()

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls, key):
        return cls._index.get(key, [])


    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = [b]
        self.c = [c]

    def extend(self, b, c):
        self.b.append(b)
        self.c.append(c)

    def __str__(self):
        return "({a}, {b}, {c})".format(**self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}({})>".format(type(self).__name__, self)


sources = [
    (2, 'B0', 'C0'),
    (3, 'B1', 'C1'),
    (5, 'B2', 'C2'),
    (2, 'B3', 'C3'),
    (4, 'B4', 'C4'),
    (4, 'B5', 'C5'),
    (2, 'B6', 'C6'),
    (3, 'B7', 'C7'),
    (5, 'B8', 'C8'),
    (2, 'B9', 'C9'),
    (4, 'B10', 'C10'),
    (2, 'B11', 'C11'),
    (2, 'B12', 'C12'),
    (4, 'B13', 'C13'),
    (2, 'B14', 'C14'),
    (4, 'B15', 'C15'),
    (4, 'B16', 'C16'),
    (3, 'B17', 'C17'),
    (4, 'B18', 'C18'),
    (1, 'B19', 'C19'),
    (3, 'B20', 'C20'),
    (4, 'B21', 'C21'),
    (5, 'B22', 'C22'),
    (1, 'B23', 'C23'),
    (3, 'B24', 'C24'),
    (4, 'B25', 'C25'),
    (3, 'B26', 'C26'),
    (2, 'B27', 'C27'),
    (4, 'B28', 'C28'),
    (5, 'B29', 'C29')
    ]

for data in sources:
    MyObj.insert(*data)

print MyObj.list_instances()
print MyObj.get_instances(5)
```

Comment: Thx! I did it differently, but using tuples as dict keys was a great reminder!